# How to see Google Cloud Compute Engine Logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

How can I see the logs regarding the VMs that has been created on Google Cloud Compute Engine ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Operations Logging (formerly Stackdriver) provides this information.

To see the details on Google Compute Engine instances that were created in a project, filter based upon the API operation `v1.compute.instances.insert` and the resouce type `resource.type=gce_instance`.

Note: the resouce type is not always necessary but it is best to be declarative in what logging should search for.

**Example using the CLI:**

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=gce_instance protoPayload.methodName=v1.compute.instances.insert" --format json
```

**Example using the Google Cloud Console - Legacy Logs Viewer**

- Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer
- Verify that the desired Google Cloud project is displayed in the title area.
- In the box showing the text "Filter by label or text search" click the dropdown and select "Convert to advanced filter".
- In the box showing the text "Filter by label or text search" enter the following (as two lines in the filter box):

  resource.type="gce_instance"

  protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.instances.insert"
- Select the desired date search range in the box "Last hour"
- Click the "Submit Filter" button

[image: Example Filtered Search]